# Render the key value of a dictionary based on an event in Django

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have two dropdowns in my .html file of Django app namely:

```
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

          <option>op1</option>


        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">

          <option>opt1</option>

        </select>
```

A dictionary is rendered from the Django views.py.I want the keys to be displayed as options in the first dropdown and whenever a key is selected,the corresponding values need to be displayed in the second dropdown.I tried some js and jina Template but no luck.How can I implement it?
I tried the following js:

```
function myFunction() {

  var dict=[];
  dict.push("{{Names}}");
  alert(Object.keys(dict));

}
```

My returned dictionary is of the form:

```
Names={1991:["cat & dog","Mat-bat","task force"],1992:["average life span!","text-user"]}
```

output:0
Django views.py:

```
def home(requests):
    return render(requests,'home/index.html',{"Names":getNames()})
```

Comment: Can you provide the javascript that you tried?

Comment: @TBK Please check the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's template rendering to populate the first dropdown, something like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    {% for key, values in yourdict %}
    <option value={{ values }}>{{ key }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Make sure to pass your dictionary variable to the template and replace "yourdict" with whatever your dictionary variable is called.

You then need to use javascript / jquery to populate the second dropdown. Add an onchange function to your first dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onchange="populateSecond()"></select>
```

Then in JS you can define that function:

```
function populateSecond() {
   var select1 = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlSelect1");       
   var select2 = document.getElementById("exampleFormControlSelect2");       
   var selectedValue = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
   selectedValue.forEach(function(element){       
       select2.appendChild(element);  
   }     
}
```

This requires that your stored values in the first dropdown are recognized as an array. Im not sure if they will be off hand, but if not you may have to convert the value of selectedValue from a string to an array using the split() method

Comment: I already tried this. but for this snippet,  ``` $('#exampleFormControlSelect1").on('change', function(){ (your code here )}``` when I select a value in first dropdown,the values corresponding to that dropdown should be displayed in second.The snippet "(your code here)" is my actual question @TBK